# What is the use of the '%' in the indexOf() method?

Tags: java

I saw some code online relating to tree maps and got curious and
want to know the use of the '%' argument in the indexOf() method.

Here's the line of code:

```
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner( dataFile );
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           String phoneEntry = scanner.nextLine();
           int separatorPosition = phoneEntry.indexOf('%');
           if (separatorPosition == -1)
              throw new IOException("File is not a phonebook data file.");
           name = phoneEntry.substring(0, separatorPosition);
           number = phoneEntry.substring(separatorPosition+1);
           phoneBook.put(name,number);
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Which `indexOf()` method exactly?

Comment: [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))? [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)? Something else?

Comment: Can you show the code also?

Comment: Yeah, I count about 19 different `indexOf` methods in JDK 8. Can you help us out by narrowing it down to specific class?

Comment: OK, you're looking at the use of `indexOf` on a `String`., with an argument of `'%'`.  What are you unsure about?

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [`String#indexOf(int ch)` java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character. If a character with value `ch` occurs in the character sequence represented by this `String` object, then the index (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned. For values of `ch` in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF (inclusive), this is the smallest value *k* such that:
>
> ```
> this.charAt(k) == ch
> ```
>
> is true. For other values of `ch`, it is the smallest value *k* such that:
>
> ```
> this.codePointAt(k) == ch
> ```
>
> is true. In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

So, there you have it. `phoneEntry.indexOf('%')` will return the index of the first character `%` in the String-value of `phoneEntry`. So if `phoneEntry` would for example hold the String-value `"50% of 50% is 25%."`, the result would be `2`, which is the 0-based index of the first `%` in this String:

```
50% of 50% is 25%.
  ^
```

If the String `phoneEntry` contains no `%`, it will result in `-1` instead.

In this case `'%'` is simply the character that is given as argument for the `.indexOf` method. If you would use `phoneEntry.indexOf('s')` instead, it would give result 12 with the same String-value:

```
50% of 50% is 25%.
            ^
```